# How to override root rem for specific div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a plugin which will be used across different websites which uses Bootstrap 4. However, Bootstrap 4 uses rem for everything. This causes issues with inconsistent sizing/spacing across different websites.

How can I override the root em for a specific div and it's children?

Comment: Apart from wrapping your plugin's elements into either an iframe or a shadow DOM (so that you could specify the _root_ font size yourself in that environment), I doubt this is actually possible.

Comment: @CBroe how does wrapping in shadow dom effect SEO?

Comment: Don't know what the stance on that in the relevant "circles" is yet, but here's a discussion on the issue in general on the web components issue tracker: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/500 I guess you could still embed your plugin "normally" (assuming that means server-side generated HTML output directly into the page source?), have that as a maybe not so pretty looking fallback, and then add JS that takes that content and "wraps" it into a shadow DOM if JS available and the browers supports SD ...